# Is swearing on the internet haram?

Tags: halal-haram, internet

Is typing a swear word on any social media platform (twitter, whatsapp, discord, etc...) without uttering it and having no intention to insult anyone haram?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it’s haram because you’ve still thought about typing the words. Control your tongue and refrain from thinking or typing these words. And although the intention is to not insult anyone the person to whom the speech is directed at may feel insulted